# Setup react app build folder onto Google Kubernetes

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-kubernetes-engine

Currently, I have a repo that contains both a Node.js Express backend and React frontend. The repo's image is in Google Container Registry and is used on a Google Kubernetes cluster. There is an url provided by a load balancer, where it is the backend url that is serving the static `build` server. In the future, I want to separate the backend/frontend into two different repos (one for backend and one for frontend).

I believe making changes for the backend in the cluster won't be difficult, but I am having trouble figuring out how to add the React frontend to this since the `build` folder will be in a different repo than the backend. I read online that to serve a React app on GCP, you would upload the `build` folder onto a bucket and have that bucket served on App Engine, which will provide a url to access it on the web.

I'm wondering if this is how it would be done on a Kubernetes cluster or if there is a different approach since it is not using App Engine, rather Google Kubernetes.

I hope this makes sense (I am still fairly new to Google Cloud) and any feedback/tips will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If your frontend doesnt do ssr you can definitely store it in a bucket

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to this.

### Approach 1: Serve your frontend via Google Cloud Storage.

There is a guide in the GCP documentation: [Hosting a static website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website?hl=en) to set this up. After the build copy all the files to the cloud storage and you are done.

### Approach 2: Add your fronted to your backend while building the Docker image

1. Build your frontend and pack it into a Docker image with something like this:

```
FROM node AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci && npm run build

FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /app/dist /app
```

2. Build your backend and copy the frontend:

```
FROM myapp/frontend as frontend

FROM node
// build backend
COPY --from=frontend /app /path/where/frontend/belongs
```

This decouples both builds but you will always have to deploy the backend for a frontend change.

### Approach 3: Serve your frontend with nginx (or another web server)

```
FROM node AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci && npm run build

FROM nginx
COPY --from=build /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
```

You might also adapt the `nginx.conf` to enable routing without hash paths. See [this article by codecentric](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2019/03/docker-angular-dockerize-app-easily/) for more information on that.